# Ranger: custom file sorting (dotfiles at the end of listing)

Tags: files, filenames, file-manager, dot-files, ranger

I am using ranger as cli file manager. I would love to order files in this way:

1. Folders alphabetically
2. Files alphabetically
3. Folders starting with `.` alphabetically
4. Files starting with `.` alphabetically

Alphabetical order is not case sensitive.

How can I achieve this ?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can write a plugin to support this. Some python knowledge is required though.

See the sample [plugin_new_sorting_method.py](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/examples/plugin_new_sorting_method.py) on how to define a new sorting method.

And check out [directory.py](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/container/directory.py) how the standard algorithms were implemented, e.g.

```
def sort_by_basename(path):
    """returns path.relative_path (for sorting)"""
    return path.relative_path


def sort_by_directory(path):
    """returns 0 if path is a directory, otherwise 1 (for sorting)"""
    return 1 - path.is_directory
```

In order to use a plugin, you need to copy it to ~/.config/ranger/plugins/